# How to get response in UDP Wi-Fi communication

Tags: android, udp, response, wif

I am working in Wifi UDP communication from android device to some hardware. I am able to send request successfully by below code

```
String json = "{\"data\":\"aaxxz\",\"command\":\"1\",\"type\":\"wificommand\",\"status\":\"request\"}";
                  int server_port = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
                  DatagramSocket s = null;
                try {
                    s = new DatagramSocket();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  InetAddress local = null;
                try {
                    local = InetAddress.getByName(ipaDD.getText().toString());
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  int msg_length=json.length();
                  byte[] message = json.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length,local,server_port);
                  try {
                    s.send(p);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
 // i wrote code to get response here. which is mentioned below
```

Above code is working like a charm without any problem, but i am not able to get response by below code.

```
try {
        s.receive(p);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

       String  text = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
       System.out.println("resp    "+text);
```

Where i am doing wrong please help me get rid this issue.